# Do NetBeans and Eclipse (including most of extensions) run on OpenJDK without original Sun JRE/JDK?

Tags: eclipse, netbeans, java

Can I install just OpenJDK without proprietary Sun JRE/JDK and use NetBeans and Eclipse without significant disadvantages?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can.
I'm using NetBeans with OpenJDK in Linux.

Answer (score 2):

You can run just OpenJDK or just Sun JDK and I'm pretty sure you can also run them side by side if you'd like with eclipse and/or netbeans. In my opinion, I think it would be best to go for Sun but if you'd really prefer to have OpenJDK instead, I believe it's pretty solid.

Comment: Why would you prefer using Sun JRE/JDK over OpenJDK then?

Comment: I prefer using Sun because 1) I believe that Sun's JRE/JDK in theory is still "more solid" compared to OpenJDK. I've heard very few users encounter odd bugs in OpenJDK 2) I don't mind using proprietary software.

Answer (score 0):

OpenJDK is supposed to be fully compatible with Sun's JDK (in fact it *is* Sun's JDK for the most part, with the proprietary parts replaced by open source software).

Almost all Java software, including NetBeans and Eclipse, runs without any problems on OpenJDK.

Comment: In theory - yes, in practice - not so much... I personally had strange issues trying to run apps on OpenJDK and they tend to push bug fixes a lot slower there...

Comment: I've used Eclipse and NetBeans on OpenJDK on Ubuntu myself, never had any strange problems. I did have some problems with programs that were checking the Java version and didn't recognise OpenJDK. That's a bug in those programs though, not in OpenJDK.